# JSON schema for inheritance structures

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to model inheritance in JSON schema. My (virtual) base class has two properties, a name (string) and a price (number). The name is used to identify the derived class. Two possible classes could be

```
{
  "Name": "ClassA",
  "Price": 12.23,
  "Color": "foobar"
}
```

or

```
{
  "Name": "ClassB",
  "Price": 12.23,
  "Size": 42
}
```

I am using "oneOf" and an enum-condition on the string to identify the derived class. The schema should look like this:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Price": {
            "type": "number"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "Name", "Price"
    ],
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/ClassA"
        },
        {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/ClassB"
        }
    ],
    "$defs": {
        "ClassA": {
            "properties": {
                "Name": {
                    "enum": [
                        "ClassA"
                    ]
                },
                "Color": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        "ClassB": {
            "properties": {
                "Name": {
                    "enum": [
                        "ClassB"
                    ]
                },
                "Size": {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work, because "additionalProperties" prohibits the base class attribute "Price".

My questions are:

1. Is this even a good approach for modeling my JSON structure? I have lots of different derived classes.
2. Should I just copy paste the base class attribute schema into each derived class and then just use "oneOf"?
3. Can I tell additionalProperties that it should only look at the attributes in the derived class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Schema doesn't model polymorphism, particularly inheritance, very well.  It's not build for that.  See [this blog post](https://modern-json-schema.com/json-schema-is-a-constraint-system) for a good explanation.

The best I have to offer is just don't use `additionalProperties` or `unevaluatedProperties` in your "base" schemas.

Note: We *are* [working](https://github.com/json-schema-org/vocab-idl) on figuring some of this out, but it's still early stages at this point.